# Access match in sed search/replace?

Tags: regex, sed

I'd like to be able to replace `1` with `1.` in a block of text I have with varying numbers.

So, how can I find out the matched digit to use in the replace?

Here's an example :

```
echo "1   MORE TEXT HERE" | sed 's/[0-9]/[0-9]\./g'
```

I'd like the `[0-9]` in the 2nd part of `sed` to give me the match.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`echo "1   MORE TEXT HERE" | sed 's/[0-9]/&\./g'`

`&` is the full match

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was something like this but couldn't find it.

Comment: Did you look in the man page? The description of `s/re/replacement/` says: _The replacement may contain the special character & to refer to that portion of the pattern space which matched_

Answer (score 0):

A solution using `gnu awk`

```
echo "1   MORE TEXT HERE" | awk '{print gensub(/[[:digit:]]*/,"&.","")}'
1.   MORE TEXT HERE
```